# Repetitive commands

Tags: cypress

I have a few tests on a page with a search input.

All the tests are basically the same except from the first one: the `type` command - that changes.

Is there any way in such a case to avoid the duplicate code on each test?

```
it('Search test1', () => {
    searchedString = '0987416572';
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').type(searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').should('be.visible'); //same for all test
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').should('have.value', searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').click(); //same for all test
    cy.contains('No results');
  });

  it('Search test2', () => {
    searchedString = 'rewretretre';
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').type(searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').should('be.visible'); //same for all test
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').should('have.value',  searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').click(); //same for all test
    cy.contains('No results');
  });

  it('Search test3', () => {
    searchedString = '1234';
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').type(searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').should('be.visible'); //same for all test
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').should('have.value', searchedString); //same for all test
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').click(); //same for all test
    cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]').should('be.visible');
  });
```

Would that make sense to add a function for the duplicates command and invoke that function? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`Custom Command`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax):

> Cypress comes with its own API for creating custom commands and
>   overwriting existing commands.

Your custom command can look like (added to `cypress/support/commands.js`):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('search', searchString => {
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').type(searchedString)
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').should('have.value', searchedString)
    cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').click()
})
```

then you can use it in your test, for example:

```
it('Search test3', () => {
    cy.search('1234')
    cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]').should('be.visible');
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Cypress docs on custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices), not everything needs to be a custom command. Functions work just fine for this case.

At the top of your file, put:

```js
 const submitSearch = (searchedString) => {
   cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').type(searchedString)
   cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').should('be.visible')
   cy.get('input[data-test="Search"]').should('have.value', searchedString)
   cy.get('span[data-test="Submit"]').click()
 }
```

then in your tests:

```js
it('Search test1', () => {
  submitSearch('0987416572')
  cy.contains('No results');
});
```